# How to write reusable "before" in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I would like to write reusable "before" section, but has failed to pass variable from main file (A.js) to imported code (HelloUtil.js). Thanks in advance for any suggestions given.

A.js

```
import * as UTIL from "./HelloUtil"

let variableFileA = "Hello"

// I hope the imported 'before' section is able to get 'variableFileA'

describe(`Do something`, () => {
    it('A "It" section', () => {
        cy.log("....")
    });
})
```

HelloUtil.js

```
before('Reusable "before" 1', () => {
    cy.log("lets begin....")
});

before('Reusable "before" 2', () => {
    cy.log("print variable:"+variableFileA)
});
```

The result that I received:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not what's going to work.

You'd need to define `variableFileA` variable in `HelloUtil.js` if you want to use the variable in there. Or you can pass the variable as an argument. But you are not doing either.

What can work is this:

**utils.js**

```js
export const beforeFunc = () => {
  cy
    .log('Before func from utils.js');
};
```

**test.js**

```js
import { beforeFunc } from './utils';

describe('My example test suite', () => {

  before(beforeFunc);
});
```

If you want to pass some argument, you can do it like so:

**utils.js**

```js
export const beforeFunc = (greetings) => {
  cy
    .log(greetings);
};
```

**test.js**

```js
import { beforeFunc } from './utils';

describe('My example test suite', () => {

  before(() => beforeFunc('Hi'));
});
```

And the result from the test runner:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would use a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands) that can be pasted in any section - be it in before, after, it etc. For example:

```
import file from 'filePath'
Cypress.Commands.add('reusableBefore2', () => {
   cy.log("print variable:" + file)
})
```

And you can call it any time with: `cy.reusableBefore2()`